# I keep getting a std::bad_alloc error in C++

Tags: c++

So I am making a program for Project Euler #14 and I have this

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector <int> CollatzSequence (int n)
{
    vector <int> numbers;
    int currentNumber = n;
    while (currentNumber != 1) {
        numbers.push_back(n);
        if (currentNumber%2 == 0) {
            currentNumber /= 2;
        } else {
            currentNumber *= 3;
            currentNumber += 1;
        }
    }
    numbers.push_back(1);
    return numbers;
}

int main()
{
    int largestNumber = 0;
    int currentNumber = 2;
    while (currentNumber < 1000000) {
        if (CollatzSequence(currentNumber).size() > largestNumber) {
            largestNumber = currentNumber;
        }
        currentNumber++;
    }
    cout << largestNumber;
    return 0;
}
```

But I keep getting this error

```cpp
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

I am new to C++ but I don't know what this error means or how to fix it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `std::bad_alloc` is thrown when there is some issue in allocating memory from the heap, usually due to insufficient memory, or insufficient contiguous memory

Comment: *So I am making a program for Project Euler #14* -- What is "Project Euler #14"?

Comment: Do you know how big the vector is? if it is very large, it might be that there is no enough memory

Comment: `std::vector` requires contigous blocks of memory

Comment: Look at that code in `CollatzSequence` *carefully*. Do you actually need to remember every number from every iteration of that loop? Look at the actual loop in `main`. All it uses is the `size()` member of the returned vector, then throws the vector away. I.e. Get rid of the vector in `CollatzSequence` and just keep a counter, returning *that* from the function.

Comment: I'm seeing `runtime error: signed integer overflow: 827370449 * 3 cannot be represented in type 'int'` ... I guess my machine is just not good enough to run this program.

Comment: You should take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876060/how-can-i-know-the-real-maximum-size-of-a-vector-not-using-stdvectormax-si). Go directly to the answers, there is explains that is the vector is unable to allocate suficient continuos space, it will throw a `std::bad_alloc`. Do you know how big is your vector?

Comment: I really think a lot of the questions being asked you could be answered by responding to my comment:  What is Project Euler #14?  Let's see exactly what you're trying to solve, the constraints etc.

Comment: @Eljay An integer overflow has nothing to do if your machine is good enough. Just use bigger ints, like a `std::uint64_t`

Comment: @Pablochaches that can't be done without changing the code. Eljay's comment still stands. Eljay, you should have bought yourself a Cray during the Black Friday sales.

Comment: A `std::bad_alloc`, if thrown, indicates that a dynamic memory allocation has failed.  Typical causes include allocating more memory than exists.   Resizing a `std::vector` (e.g. using `push_back()`) tends to allocate memory, as does copying one (since two vectors must each dynamically manage their own memory).   Your `CollatzSequence()` function repeatedly resizes a vector, then (notionally at least) returns a copy of that vector to the caller.

Comment: Hard to see what the actual problem being solved with this code was regardless. This code compares an iteration count for a given input number to the prior *input number* (i.e. not some prior input number's iteration count). If the goal was to remember the number that had the highest iteration count, that's not the way to do it. You need to remember *two* numbers: 1. the highest iteration count, and 2. the number that generated that iteration count. Doing what you're doing vs. what I just described will yield two different answers. Make sure you know which one is expected.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler014/problem (literally the first Google result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::bad_alloc` is thrown when allocation of memory fails, in your code this happens when allocating memory for `std::vector` returned. `std::vector` requires contiguous memory, in your code, the size to be allocated might be causing the problem.

as @WhozCraig said in the comments, the function has no need to return the vector itself since only the size is used rather, simply add a counter inside the function and return that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int CollatzSequence(int n)
{
    int currentNumber = n;
    int counter = 0;
    while (currentNumber != 1) {
        ++counter;
        if (currentNumber%2 == 0) {
            currentNumber /= 2;
        } else {
            currentNumber *= 3;
            currentNumber += 1;
        }
    }
    ++counter;
    return counter;
}

int main()
{
    int largestNumber = 0;
    int currentNumber = 2;
    while (currentNumber < 1000000) {
        if (CollatzSequence(currentNumber) > largestNumber) {
            largestNumber = currentNumber;
        }
        currentNumber++;
    }
    cout << largestNumber;
    return 0;
}
```

maybe also consider moving from `int` to `std::uint64_t` like @Pablochaches suggested in the comments